# e.preventDefault not working — jquery

Tags: jquery, css, events, hyperlink

I have some simple code. I'm still fumbling around this jquery malark, so be easy.

I'm trying to stop those pesky hastags taking the user to the top of the page whenever they are clicked.

The website in question is this: [studiojubilee.com/pattern.](http://studiojubilee.com/pattern) If you scroll down the page, then click on clients / information, the page jolts to the top. I'm trying to fix it with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('html').fadeIn(800);
        $('#information').click(function(e) {
            $("#gutter, #us").fadeToggle(600);
        });
        $('#clients').click(function(e) {
            $("ul, #gutter").fadeToggle(600);
        });

        $('#title').click(function(e) {
            $("#gutter").fadeToggle(600);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="clients"><a href="#">Clients</a></div>

<div id="title"><a href="#">Studio Jubilee</a></div>

<div id="information"><a href="#">Information</a></div>
```

I'm aware this probably looks stupid to anyone with any sort of expertise. Help a brother out?

Tom

Comment: Have you considered using `javascript: void false;` instead of `#` on links?

Comment: try put e.preventDefault(); as first line in event handler function

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
$('#title').click(function(e) { ...
```

Isn't being called, as only the center link has this id.

Use a class instead.

```
<div id="clients"><a class="prevent-default" href="#">Clients</a></div>

<script>
    $('.prevent-default').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the title here.. If it is a div I don't think it has any default event associated it with it..

For example if you are using an **anchor**  tag , its default functionality is to take to a specific link.. If you do preventDefault then it makes some sense.. But not in other cases

If you use a button then doing this will prevent the default  functionality of the button click event..

Comment: Good catch. It is a div. The id needs to be moved to the anchor tag

Comment: id needs to be moved to the anchor tag?